# Openlayers PDO PDOException: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'identifier'

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript, location

I installed openlayers 3.X and used it a little bit. Then I uninstalled openlayers 3.x and installed openlayers 2.x.

Now when I click on openlayers > maps I get the following error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'identifier' in 'where clause': SELECT t__0.* FROM
>   {openlayers_projections} t__0 WHERE (identifier IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => EPSG:4326 ) in ctools_export_load_object()
>
> (line 462 of D:\wamp\www\whaymeat\sites\all\modules\ctools\includes\export.inc).

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you disable and the uninstall explicitly the module or you just disble it, delete the 3.x release and then added the 2.x release and enable it?

Comment: I disabled in modules and uninstalled it explicity in tab uninstall in drupal. Then deleted it from the modules folder.